# Duplicated ID in user editable database: how to give unique ID numbers?

Tags: c#, duplicates

I have been searching for a solution for my problem, but nothing would be quite what I need. So, here it is.

In my Windows Forms App, I have a `TreeView` populated by a `List<material_data>` that serves as my Database.

```c#
public class material_data
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double[] Data { get; set; }
    }

public void PopulateTreeView (List<material_data> database, TreeView treeView)
    {
        foreach (material_data material in database)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode { 
                Name = material.ID.ToString(),
                Text = material.Description, 
                Tag = material.Data
            };

            treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
```

The user can manipulate this `List<material_data>` by:

1. Adding items. Only `material_data.Description` and `material_data.Data` are given as user input, while `material_data.ID` is set programmatically. *Added `material_data` items can be saved to a binary file*.
2. Edit items. Only `material_data.Description` and `material_data.Data` can be edited, `material_data.ID` is conserved. Changes are saved to the original binary file.
3. Deleting items. Binary files are not deleted, so *deleted items can be added again with the saved binary file*.

After any change to the `List<material_data>`, the TreeView is updated. My first approach was to set the new ID as the largest ID in the list plus 1. However, if the largest ID was deleted and then a new material is added, a duplicated ID would be created and the user would not be able to recover the old material from the binary file. Another flaw is that I quickly lose track of ID numbers because of the save/load of binary files.

My next solution was to store a `CounterID` User Setting, so that the ID count never goes back, even after deleting items or closing the session.

```c#
int ID_Counter = Properties.Settings.Default.CounterID;

ID_Counter++;
new_material.ID = ID_Counter;

Properties.Settings.Default.CounterID = ID_Counter;
```

It was successful, but if an error occurs on the Settings file (as happened when my PC suddenly shutdown while I was programming) and the counter gets reset, it would mess up all future sessions.

Is there any other approach to the problem of duplicated IDs in this case? Or I should reconsider the idea of saving and loading binary files to the database?

As I am relatively new to Visual Studio/C#, I suspect that there are other functionalities that I am not exploring. I don't know if using a `DataTable` or a SQL database would be better, but a simple `List<>` seemed to be enough for my case.

Comment: Can you change your ID from an `int` to a [Guid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx)? That would solve the problem neatly.

Comment: Yes, I was just a bit reluctant to use it before because of the very very small chance of getting the same Guid. But I guess I can come up with something to prevent that too. It a much more cleaner solution. Thank you

Comment: Every time that the program starts set the counter of your second approach to the biggest already stored value + 1.